# How to disable proxy in visual studio code?

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.37.1 (user setup).

My enviroment has http_proxy and https_proxy variables set. In same rare moments I need to push or pull without using the proxy.

[image]

With http.proxy variable I can change the proxy but I cannot unset it.

I need to unset proxy inside Visual Studio Code without exiting it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but might be a help to someone in the future.

There is a specific extension for VSCODE - **Toggle Proxy by satokaz**.

It allows you to quickly turn off your proxy settings with one click. Extension will comment it out for you.

Comment: Does it work in VS Code 1.62.3? When I click on the toolbar icon, I get "Callback must be a function. Received undefined" error.