# Visual Studio code does not corrently handle HTTPS connection over proxy

Tags: proxy, https, visual-studio-code

It seems like I have a misconfiguration issue. The top of the iceberg is the following error in VS Code v1.62.3 console:

```
> Executing task: C:\Users\Test\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe update <

Updating platformio/contrib-piohome   3.4.0 @ ~3.4.0  Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.registry.ns1.platformio.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/packages/platformio/tool/contrib-piohome (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))
The terminal process "C:\Users\Test\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe 'update'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I have system-wide proxy configured (Windows Settings → Network & Internet → Proxy), but no `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables set.

VS Code has the following settings:

```
{
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
  "http.proxy": ""
}
```

The first issue is that with this setup VS Code still tries to connect the proxy.
The second issue is that it communicates to the proxy in a wrong way:

```
02:12:58.936212 IP laptop.62953 > proxy.3128: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 256, length 517
        0x0020:                      1603 0102 0001 0001  ................
        0x0030:  fc03 03e9 84e1 cff8 6b1e 15d6 9ea6 9ee6  ........k.......
        0x0040:  1f66 f9ca 620a cf4d e968 e33d c71e ae3a  .f..b..M.h.=...:
        0x0050:  4919 8f20 64b6 a0ae 2a0d e44b 88e4 d1bf  I...d...*..K....
        0x0060:  4353 ae17 cf88 612a 5a85 d50e 3468 828a  CS....a*Z...4h..
...
02:12:58.936268 IP proxy.3128 > laptop.62953: Flags [.], ack 518, win 501, length 0
02:12:58.936607 IP proxy.3128 > laptop.62953: Flags [.], seq 1:1461, ack 518, win 501, length 1460
        0x0020:                      4854 5450 2f31 2e31  ........HTTP/1.1
        0x0030:  2034 3030 2042 6164 2052 6571 7565 7374  .400.Bad.Request
        0x0040:  0d0a 5365 7276 6572 3a20 7371 7569 640d  ..Server:.squid.
        0x0050:  0a4d 696d 652d 5665 7273 696f 6e3a 2031  .Mime-Version:.1
        0x0060:  2e30 0d0a 4461 7465 3a20 4d6f 6e2c 2032  .0..Date:.Mon,.2
        0x0070:  3920 4e6f 7620 3230 3231 2030 313a 3132  9.Nov.2021.01:12
        0x0080:  3a35 3820 474d 540d 0a43 6f6e 7465 6e74  :58.GMT..Content
        0x0090:  2d54 7970 653a 2074 6578 742f 6874 6d6c  -Type:.text/html
        0x00a0:  3b63 6861 7273 6574 3d75 7466 2d38 0d0a  ;charset=utf-8..
        0x00b0:  436f 6e74 656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20  Content-Length:.
        0x00c0:  3333 3236 0d0a 582d 5371 7569 642d 4572  3326..X-Squid-Er
        0x00d0:  726f 723a 2045 5252 5f50 524f 544f 434f  ror:.ERR_PROTOCO
        0x00e0:  4c5f 554e 4b4e 4f57 4e20 300d 0a56 6172  L_UNKNOWN.0..Var
...
```

As one can see the client does not send `CONNECT api.registry.ns1.platformio.org:443` to the proxy but instead sends SSL data to the proxy. The proxy replies:

```
NONE/400 3689 NONE error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Additionally I have tried below configuration which don't work as well:

```
{
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
  "http.proxy": "",
  "https.proxy": "",
  "http.proxySupport": no
}
```

Also I tried to start VS Code with `--no-proxy-server` argument, also with no effect: VS Code still goes via proxy.

##### Related articles

- [Problems with proxy in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404000/problems-with-proxy-in-vscode)
- [How to disable proxy in visual studio code?](https://superuser.com/questions/1490731/how-to-disable-proxy-in-visual-studio-code)
  That extension actually didn't work for me, when trying to click on "off" icon it causes "Callback must be a function. Received undefined" error:
  [image: Error screenshot]
- [Network Connections in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network)